# Invalid Script Error using Toad

Tags: mysql, variables, syntax, toad

I'm trying to develop the SQL statement for a stored procedure that will provide me with a number of counts that I will specify with a variable (@repeated).

I'm using Toad for MySQL and I keep getting syntax errors (which aren't very descriptive). Here is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @repeated INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE @mailingmonth DATE;

SET @mailingmonth = '2015-10-01';

WHILE @repeated < 12 DO
SELECT A.LoanNumber, Repeated FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist A 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT LoanNumber, COUNT(*) As Repeated
             FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist B
             WHERE MailingMonth <= @mailingmonth
             GROUP BY LoanNumber) AS Months ON A.LoanNumber = Months.LoanNumber
 WHERE A.MailingMonth = @mailingmonth
 AND Repeated = @repeated
 SET @repeated = @repeated + 1;
 END WHILE;
 END;
```

I think there are probably several issues with this syntax, but I keep making changes and nothing seems to work.

## **UPDATE**

I want to encapsulate similar code in a stored procedure with parameters so that I can change the parameters to suit my needs. This is what I have:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE procedure sp_MKT_Counts_Test2 (vRepeated INT, vMailingmonth DATE)
BEGIN

WHILE vRepeated < 12 DO
SELECT COUNT(A.LoanNumber) FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist A 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT LoanNumber, COUNT(*) As Repeated
             FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist B
             WHERE MailingMonth <= vMailingmonth
             GROUP BY LoanNumber) AS Months ON A.LoanNumber = Months.LoanNumber
 WHERE A.MailingMonth = vMailingmonth
 AND Repeated = vRepeated;
 SET vRepeated = vRepeated + 1;
 END WHILE;
  END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I call the stored procedure with the two parameters, I merely get a message informing me that the statement executed successfully, but I get no result set. Why is there no result set? Do I need an output parameter?

Comment: If you are on mysql, yo need write "DO", after the while condition: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: BEGIN will only work in a stored program such as procedure or trigger.Are you working inside a procedure?

Comment: Mihai -- I will encapsulate this code in a procedure once I have made it work. I removed the BEGIN command upon your advice; thank you.

Okay, I also placed DO after "WHILE @repeated < 12"

Comment: Now it's flagging "DECLARE @repeated INT DEFAULT 1" as containing a syntax error.

Comment: Read here the first proposition https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flow-control-statements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you past the syntax error(s):

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure myProc876()
BEGIN

DECLARE vRepeated INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vMailingmonth DATE;

SET vMailingmonth = '2015-10-01';

WHILE vRepeated < 12 DO
SELECT A.LoanNumber, Repeated FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist A 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT LoanNumber, COUNT(*) As Repeated
             FROM MKT_Mailing_Hist B
             WHERE MailingMonth <= mailingmonth
             GROUP BY LoanNumber) AS Months ON A.LoanNumber = Months.LoanNumber
 WHERE A.MailingMonth = vMailingmonth
 AND Repeated = vRepeated;
 SET vRepeated = vRepeated + 1;
 END WHILE;
 END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

It has a WHILE **DO**, changes some variable names, and is wrapped with the DELIMITER. The delimiter is important because otherwise the first semi-colon found ends it all. So the $$ wraps the whole thing. Then sets the user session delimiter back to a semi-colon.

Note that your `AND Repeated = @repeated` had no semi at the end too

[Delimiters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html) are important with stored procs and create event and triggers.

Comment: This works superbly. Is there a reason why, in the subquery, "mailingmonth" didn't need to be called "vMailingmonth"?

Comment: to be honest, I wanted to separate the ambiguity. Plus half the time I don't know whether to use @ or not